how to verify the minimum gas fee for deploying a contract on the mainnet?
how to verify the minimum gas fee for deploying a contract on the mainnet?
my contract creation failed in Remix IDE, I choosed estimated gas fee and the process were not successfully finished, is it the cause?

3,000,000 | 3,000,000 (100%)
Gas Fees:
Base: 10.686194745 Gwei |Max: 11.801548558 Gwei |Max Priority: 1 Gwei
Burnt & Txn Savings Fees:
Burnt: 0.032058584235 ETH ($113.22)
Txn Savings: 0.000346061439 ETH ($1.22)
Other Attributes:
Txn Type: 2 (EIP-1559)
Nonce: 0
Position In Block: 102

A method to verify costs of deploy a contract using remix IDE is to deploy the contract in a VM, might be a simulated one in remix, just use the most updated (VM Shanghai currently). Inspect the logs and one can find the transaction and execution costs:

Transaction cost and execution costs are explained in details here: What is the difference between transaction cost and execution cost in remix?.
The total cost is transaction cost + execution costs and the price, in ETH, can be calculated using the current gas price in the network. Currently (med gas price of 15 Gwei) this deploy should cost:
(799737+692625) × 15Gwei ~ 0.0224 eth + priority fee

than you so much

so i should use custom section and enter the whole amount ? i receive this on the mainnet"Gas estimation failed
Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
Returned error: gas required exceeds allowance (325344)
[object Object]" and what should I put on the next step (another pop up message) it includes "Max Priority fee:
1
Gwei
Max fee (Not less than base fee 8.393169599 Gwei):
8.393169599
Gwei" would you try the Magatrump contract and tell me how to fill each field in order to prevent failure

This message: "Gas estimation failed" indicate that probably there is some error in your solidity code, or some execution error emmited. I suggest you to hit the debug button  to try to figure out what is wrong or post your code in a question, someone may help you. Force send should not fix anythink.

thank you for your prompt response, i'll send it, would you please take a look at it pls?

@Rafael Perfect, can you tell me from which website we can get the Gas Price = 15Gwei and can we also get the Priority Fee ?

@Rafael I think this site giving mine answer: https://etherscan.io/gastracker

Estimation of Gas Fees:
I tried to deploy a simple contract on Sepolia testnet and observed the MetaMask popup without confirming the transaction. This gave me a live estimate of gas fees, as seen in this screenshot where the estimated fee was approximately 0.00315842 SepoliaETH ($12.05).
Contract:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract GasPrice {
    address public myAddr = 0xAb8483F64d9C6d1EcF9b849Ae677dD3315835cb2;
}


NOTE:
Ensure the gas limit and max fee are set appropriately based on the contract's complexity and current network conditions. Sometimes due to high traffic metamask shows high gas fee and the process for calculating the fee is continuously changes.

thank you Ahmad for your response, but I have even put higher gas, but I receive this error:  Returned error: gas required exceeds allowance (325344)

@Morty normally this error coming due to an issue in your solidity code.

@Morty may be this error can be the solidity version issue, so you can post the code i will try to solve it at my end.
